# Schur's Lemma (Riemannian Geometry)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.  Assume that 
$$
\text{sec}_p(\pi) = f(p) \qquad\text{  for all } 2-\text{planes } \pi \subset T_pM \text{ and for all } p \in M.
$$
Where sec$_p(\pi)$ is the sectional curvature at $p$ and $f$ is some smooth function on $M$.

I need to prove that there is a smooth function $g$ on $M$ such that $$\text{Ric}(v) = g(p) \cdot v \qquad \text{for all }v \in T_pM \text{ and for all } p \in M.$$

How can I show that?